# Стилизация стрелочки по умолчанию в input type="time"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Всем привет.

Есть такая проблема что надо менять стрелочки в `input type="time"` обычные стрелки  у меня получаетсья менять  но чтобы менять их и потом все работало вот это сложновато.

Внизу пример `input type="number"` все работает

```js
 $('.number .number_controls > div').on('click', function() {
      let input = $(this).closest('.number').find('input'); // input
      let value = parseInt(input.val()) || 0; // getting input value  OR 0
      if ($(this).hasClass('nc-minus')) {
        value = value - 1; // Minus from value 1
      }
      if ($(this).hasClass('nc-plus')) {
        value = value + 1; // Plus to value 1
      }
      input.val(value).change(); // выводим полученное value в инпут; триггер .change() - на случай, если на изменение этого инпута у вас уже объявлен еще какой-то обработчик
    });
```

```css
input[type='number'] {
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
} 
.number {
    position: relative;
    width: 160px;
}
.number input {
    height: 30px;
}
      
.number_controls {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 30px;
    z-index: 5;
}
.nc-plus > .fa {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: $simple-orange;
}
.nc-minus > .fa {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: $simple-orange;
}
.number_controls>div {
    width: 30px;
    height: 15px;
    line-height: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
}
    input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
    input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="number">
    <input type="number" class="form-control" value="0"/>
    <div class="number_controls">
        <div class="nc-plus"><i class="fa fa-caret-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
        <div class="nc-minus"><i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Но такой же код не проходит с `input type="time"`

Он проста не работает ..Помогите пожалуйста решить данную проблему

Comment: Потому что у  type="time", другой формат данных. А что должны стрелки менять? Часы или минуты?

Comment: @Lukas ну как обычно должны работать стрелки по умолчанию.Как работают свои родные стрелки time-а так и должны работать стилизованные стрелки .

Comment: родные стрелки у input time, есть только в opera и chrome. Не понятно как проверить фокус стоит на часах или минутах. Может кто-то сталкивался и подскажет)

Comment: @Lukas хорошо :(